# PHP Update Select Tag From The Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 `<select>` dropdowns. On the first `<select>` I have **2,4,6** as options. On the second `<select>` I have **3,6,9** and on the third `<select>` I have **4,8,12**. The user only need to choose one. For example, if she chose **2** on the first `<select>` then she's not allowed to choose on the other `<select>` aymore. And then when the Save button was clicked it will be saved on the database.

The problem is when I tried to update my data like choose another option and saved it, nothing change. Below are my codes.

**This is how I call my data from the database.**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pass", "db");

$edit=$_GET['id'];
$select="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$edit'";

$run=mysqli_query($con,$select);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);

$id=$row['id'];
$num=$row['num'];

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">

            <select type="text" name="num">
               <option disabled selected>Twos</option>
               <option value="two">2</option>
               <option value="four">4</option>
               <option value="six">6</option>
            </select>

            <select type="text" name="num">
               <option disabled selected>Threes</option>
               <option value="three">3</option>
               <option value="six">6</option>
               <option value="nine">9</option>
            </select>

            <select type="text" name="num">
               <option disabled selected>Fours</option>
               <option value="four">4</option>
               <option value="eight">8</option>
               <option value="twelve">12</option>
            </select>

            <label>Number: </label>
            <select type="text" name="num">
                <option><?php echo $num; ?></option> //this is where I want to display the data from the db
            </select>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And this is my php code.**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['update'])){

    $up_id=$_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_POST['num'])){
        $num_u=$_POST['num'];

        $update="UPDATE table SET num='$num_u' WHERE id='$up_id'";

        $run_u=mysqli_query($con,$update);
        if ($run_u){
            echo "<script>alert('Record Updated Successfully')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('view.php', '_self')</script>";
        }else {
            echo "<script>alert('Record Update Failed!!')</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Select Atleast one num!!')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

I'm aware about my problem regarding `SQL Injection` I will fix that after I am done here. I'm still learning and a help from you guys will be so much appreciated. I hope you guys can help me. Thank you so much.

**SNIPPET**

```html
<html>

<body>
 <form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
  <label>First Choices: </label>
  <select type="text" name="num">
    <option disabled selected>Twos</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="six">6</option>
  </select> <br>

  <label>Second Choices: </label>
  <select type="text" name="num">
    <option disabled selected>Threes</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="six">6</option>
    <option value="nine">9</option>
  </select> <br>

  <label>First Choices: </label>
  <select type="text" name="num">
    <option disabled selected>Fours</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="eight">8</option>
    <option value="twelve">12</option>
  </select> <br><br>

  <label>Number: </label>
  <select type="text" name="num">
    <option>Data from DB here
    </option> //this is where I want to display the data from the db
  </select> <br><br>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make code snippet

Comment: Where do you connect to the database in the update code?

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: They're all on the same `.php` file. @Shadow

Comment: There you go. I hope it helps. @pal

Comment: you also have to use a **form tag** love to submit the form over a particular URL, adding the URL to the action property of the form tag you can get it more from here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_form_tag.htm

Comment: yaa excetly use from tag to send your data on submit which php script you want to run

Comment: Yup, I have that I also I just didn't put my whole codes in here bcs it'll be messy hehe @MohdSamganKhan

Comment: if value is selected from one drop-dwon than you have to disbale other two drop-dwon ?? @desteen

Comment: Omg yes exactly like that!! @pal

Comment: @desteen your code seems to be broken, can you please provide the complete content of the file as I am assuming the complete code is in one file only. Don't care about the mess, we are here to help clean the mess...

Comment: using jquery change event to update database value by new selected value

Comment: is the data saved first time???

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by using javascript and I found a bug in your code that you are not using `form` tag.
 I have done a sample, the code given below:

```
<?php
   $num=2;
?>
<form action="your_backend_file_name.php" method="POST">
    <select type="text" name="num">
       <option disabled selected>Twos</option>
       <option value="two">2</option>
       <option value="four">4</option>
       <option value="six">6</option>
    </select>

    <select type="text" name="num">
       <option disabled selected>Threes</option>
       <option value="three">3</option>
       <option value="six">6</option>
       <option value="nine">9</option>
    </select>

    <select type="text" name="num">
       <option disabled selected>Fours</option>
       <option value="four">4</option>
       <option value="eight">8</option>
       <option value="twelve">12</option>
    </select>

    <label>Number: </label>
    <select type="text" name="num">
        <option disabled selected>Data from db</option>
        <option value="dbData"><?= $num ?></option> //this is where I want to display the data from the db
    </select>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
    </div>
</form>
```

And Add javascript code given below:

```
<script>
    var radios = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('select[name=num]'));

    radios.forEach(function(radio) {
        radio.addEventListener('change', function() { 
            radios.forEach(function(r) {
                r.disabled = r !== radio;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I have printed what data coming from front end to the backend file named `your_backend_file_name.php`. `your_backend_file_name.php` , this file consist of the following code:

```
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST)){
      print_r($_POST);
  }
?>
```

Check this snippet:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="your_backend_file_name.php" method="POST">
            <select type="text" name="num">
                <option disabled selected>Twos</option>
                <option value="two">2</option>
                <option value="four">4</option>
                <option value="six">6</option>
            </select>

            <select type="text" name="num">
                <option disabled selected>Threes</option>
                <option value="three">3</option>
                <option value="six">6</option>
                <option value="nine">9</option>
            </select>

            <select type="text" name="num">
                <option disabled selected>Fours</option>
                <option value="four">4</option>
                <option value="eight">8</option>
                <option value="twelve">12</option>
            </select>

            <label>Number: </label>
            <select type="text" name="num">
                <option disabled selected>Data from db</option>
                <option value="dbData">123</option> //this is where I want to display the data from the db
            </select>

            <div>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>

<script>
    var radios = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('select[name=num]'));

    radios.forEach(function (radio) {
        radio.addEventListener('change', function () {
            radios.forEach(function (r) {
                r.disabled = r !== radio;
            });
        });
    });
    
    $("#resetbtn").click(function(){
    $( 'form select[name=num]' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
    });
</script>
```